# json_object() and `group by` Optimisation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, performance, optimization, query-optimization

i've got an optimisation problem with my query, once I use the aggregate `GROUP BY` in my query with a `JSON_OBJECT()`, the performances are heavily affected, and it seems that the `JSON_OBJECT()` function is called for EVERY row in the table, even if there is a `LIMIT`.

Once there is no more `GROUP BY`, the query is executed really fast. I abstracted the query i'm using to the easiest, but I need to `GROUP BY` cause

I'm using JSON_ARRAYAGG() for another join.

I got ~25k rows in my table and it takes 10x less time when removing the group by aggregate

```
select JSON_OBJECT('id',`b`.`id`) as bw 
from a 
    left join `b` on `a`.`id` = `b`.`id_a` 
group by `a`.`id` 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hi it is not necessary to SHOUT your title

Comment: @RiggsFolly Indeed, thanks for the edit

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: mysql has to read every row to decode the json in order to then do any calculations or group bys.

Comment: @FreudianSlip But how can I create my json objects and arrays AFTER that group by ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, JSON should be used for storing structured data that *only* the app needs to look inside.  It is clumsy and probably *very* inefficient for MySQL to pick apart JSON for use with `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, etc.

As for `GROUP BY` (or `ORDER BY`) plus `LIMIT 1`:

With just the `LIMIT`, MySQL simply peels of the first row it finds. -- much faster, *but* which row you get is unpredictable.

With Group or Order, it *may* have to gather all possible rows, juggle them (grouping or sorting), and *only then* peel off 1 row. -- much slower.

It sounds like you have an "array" of things in each JSON?  The RDBMS equivalent involves a second *table* to handle all those arrays -- one element per row.  Switching to that *may* lead to much faster code.  (I don't understand your data well enough to give you a concrete suggestion.)